# Python transfer Excel files between socket server and client

Tags: python, sockets

As title, I would like to know how socket programming transfer Excel files across the stream. I can send and receive any txt file using `open` method and read the file, convert it into binary string and send across the socket stream, but I am in nowhere how to send a complicated file type like xlsx/xls over the stream.

Here is my sample code on how to send a file via socket. But this only applicable for files that can be open using the `open` method. What if I want to send other files like PDF, xlsx, etc?

Server:

```
class Server:

    def __init__(self, host_ip_address, host_port):
        self._host_ip_address = host_ip_address
        self._host_port = host_port
        self._socket = socket.socket()
        self._connection = None
        self._address = None
        self._chunk_size = 0
        self._process = None
        self._queue = None

    def start_connection(self):
        try:
            self._socket.bind((self._host_ip_address, self._host_port))
            self._socket.listen(0)
        except socket.error:
            raise Exception('Unable to initiate the server connection, please check the socket')

    def receive_file(self, queue):
        try:
            connection, address = self._socket.accept()
            filename = 'stream_file.txt'
            with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
                while True:
                    file_data = connection.recv(self._chunk_size)
                    if not file_data:
                        break
                    file.write(f'{file_data}')
            queue.put(filename)
        except Exception as err:
            raise Exception('There is an issue while receiving the file, please try again')

    def start_server(self, chunk_size=4096):
        self._queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self._chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.start_connection()
        self._process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.receive_file, args=(self._queue,))
        self._process.start()
        print(self._queue.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server('127.0.0.1', 5001)
    server.start_server()
```

Client:

```
class Client:

    def __init__(self, host_ip_address, host_port):
        self._host_ip_address = host_ip_address
        self._host_port = host_port
        self._socket = socket.socket()
        self._chunk_size = 0

    def start_connection(self):
        try:
            self._socket.connect((self._host_ip_address, self._host_port))
        except socket.error:
            raise Exception('Unable to connect to the host')
            
    def send_file(self, filename):
        try:
            file = open(filename, 'rb')
            while True:
                read_bytes = file.read(self._chunk_size)
                if not read_bytes:
                    break
                self._socket.sendall(read_bytes)
        except Exception as err:
            raise Exception('No file has been selected. Please make sure the file exist')
            
    def start_client(self, chunk_size=4096, file=None):
        if data is None:
            raise Exception('No data selected to send across the socket')
        self._chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.start_connection()

        self.send_file(data_type, file)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client('127.0.0.1', 5001)
    filename = r'D:\Work\sample.xlsx'
    client.start_client(file=filename)
```

Comment: Every file is just a sequence of bits, once you opened the file in binary mode you can transfer the bits that construct that file and just reconstruct it when you write it (again, as binary). The only thing you need to add to your transfer is the file name (including extension)

Comment: @AlmogDavid so do you mean you can use the same open(file, 'rb') method to read the excel file into bits?

Comment: Exactly, at the end any file is just a sequence of bytes

Comment: why don't you think you can open them with the `open` method?

Comment: To my knowledge reading excel with open method will not be able to read the actual content of the excel.